# Static image with scrollable text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

```
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      // adding App Bar
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          SvgPicture.asset(
            "assets/images/Moto.svg",
            width: 50,
            height: 100,
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined),
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: const Text(
          "Version:1.38-alpha(10308)",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: const MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: const Expanded(
          // SingleChildScrollView contains a
          // single child which is scrollable
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            // for Vertical scrolling
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Text(`
```

Comment: Hi, it seems you're new here. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We cannot help you when it's unclear what your question is.

Comment: explain what you need to acheive

Comment: i want a scrollview in page and i want my image to be static that means when i scroll the page image should not scroll only the text should be scrolled, this is what i need

Comment: Use a Stack with children Image and ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple wrap your Expanded widget with stack and add the image widget as a first child to the stack.

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Sample UI'),
    ),
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        SizedBox.expand(
          child: Image.network(
            'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1624496/pexels-photo-1624496.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: List.generate(100,(index) => 
                Text(
                  'Hello welcome $index',
                   style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                   ),
                )
             ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  )
```

[image: Scrolable list of texts with bg image]